# Can't Deploy DataLab: 401 Locked Domain Expired error

Tags: google-cloud-datalab

When trying to deploy Datalab it fails with the following error message in the log file:

```
{"error":{"errors":[{"domain":"global","reason":"lockedDomainExpired","message":"Locked Domain Expired"}],"code":401,"message":"Locked Domain Expired"}}
```

Looking at the serial log output for the datalab deploy VM the last line is:

```
Dec 28 18:11:37 datalab-deploy-main-20151228-18-09-56 startupscript: Finished running startup script /var/run/google.startup.script
```

Answer (score 1):

I also encountered this same error message when trying to view the log file about 10 minutes from the time I clicked 'deploy datalab'. Since the log file is hosted at a temporary url, I believe the error is indicating that the log file you are trying to view is no longer available (expired). If you are able to start datalab successfully, then you can ignore the error indicating that the log file is not available. Visit the following [link](https://datalab.cloud.google.com/) and click start to check to see if datalab starts up successfully.

Comment: Unfortunately, for us the datalab never gets deployed, so going back to that page the only option is to "deploy" again.

Comment: The error message is not sufficient to help solve the specific issue (as it is a common message caused by a temporary log being created). Can you find any other error messages that may be helpful?

Answer (score -1):

If you create a completely new project, you'll be able to deploy Datalab to it.
I don't know why it doesn't deploy to my existing projects.